# Is there any built in variable in python class to know if the __init__ is called for the first time?

Tags: python, variables, init

During the first call of `__init__` function I wanted to set dynamically some class variables accessing them as follows: `self.__class__.variable = obj`

Of course I want to do it only once, so I can do something like:

```
class A:
  variable = None
  def __init__(self, obj):
    if self.__class__.variable is None:
      self.__class__.variable = obj
```

I was just curious if there is some more neat way, to make this if statement (or maybe there is entirely other way, of setting such variables)?

Comment: No, Python doesn't track method calling or variable access, you will need to provide that functionality yourself, for example with what you're doing.

Comment: You can replace `self.__class__.variable` with `A.variable` if you want it to look nicer. Will behave differently with derived classes, though.